# UITableView over UITableViewCell didSelectMethod

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

This must be stupid question,

Some how I know the reason but difficult to find solution.
So any help will be welcome..

What I am having is, one `UITableView` with header.
Header contains the Question and `UITableViewCell` contains the options to question.

Each cell is having 3 controls,
2 Labels and 1 button.

1 label contain Option and other contains its answer.
To match the answer you have to select option from drop down, which is opened when button from that cell is clicked.

That drop down is again a `UITableView`.
Which options.
So that DropDownTableView is added over UITableViewCell.

but problem is that when I open drop down on that cell, the table goes beyond boundary of cell,
So `DidSelectMethod` of DropDown table is not getting called.

I can't increase the height of `BaseTableVieCell`, but I want to select option from DropDownTable.

What should I do.

I tried `bringSubviewToFront`, and also disabling the `baseTableView` when Button is clicked.

But didn't helped.

Is there any other way to achieve the task.

Thanks for help.

Here is the picture which will give detail idea.

[image]

I am not able to select option "A", "B" , "C" as they go out of boundary of cell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can resize the height of that particular cell and set it as cell.height+smallTableview.height, using beginUpdates and endUpdates

Comment: @z22 :- Can u please little bit elaborate the answer, I didn't get you

Comment: @stallone you need to resize a particular cell height if you are going to show a dropdown list within the cell boundary. Right now the cell boundary height is 44 and dropdown list is showing out of bounds of cell that is why its only clickable at the point your arrow is pointing.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman :- I knw that thing, but I can't increase the cell height. Is there any way that when I clicked the button then height of the cell increase to my drop down table height and comes to normal height as soon as I select option from drop down table

Comment: @stallone if the height of your dropdown list is fixed suppose 50 then upon tap of button you need to return the row height of that particular cell to cellHeight+50 from the tableview delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @stallone- check my answer to get a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to resize the cell whose button is clicked as follows:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect rect = cell.frame;
    rect.size.height = 150.0;
    ht = 150.0; // declared previously. you may check in the attached project
    selected = indexPath.row;
    [cell setFrame:rect];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I have just given you an idea on how you will resize the cell. Here I have taken a static height(150.0). Instead of that you will have to give the height of your inner `tableView` that gets dropped down on `UIButton` click.

You can find demo project to change the cell height dynamically [here](https://github.com/godara/tableViewDynamicCellHeightDemo).

Hope that helps.